# click save, show confirm message goes to if condition before prompt

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a save button, when clicked if a certain condition is met a `confirm` message is shown, on `true` it was supposed to continue `click` of save button but that being `unbinded` I called click inside. but it did not work.

**Problem Found**

jquery is executing `if` condition of `confirm` before even `confirm` is shown and then after `OK` is pressed it just do nothing.

**My Work**

When the button is pressed, if `oA` variable is 0 which mean we have not visited `onceAllowed` function then it is visited otherwise not. 
The code is here:

```js
var oA = 0;
var condition = true;//dummy condition
 $('body').off("click", "#btnSave");
 $('body').on("click", "#btnSave", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       if (oA == 0) {
             if (!onceAllowed()) { return false; };
       };
       saveForm(); 
 });
function onceAllowed() {
     if (condition && oA == 0) {
         var ldays = true;
         //shows confirm box later, then skip everything
         ldays = confirm("Only " + $('#LDAtOnce').text() + " Day(s) are allowed. Click Ok to proceed anyway");
         if (ldays === false) {
              debugger;
              //This is where it always end up   
              return false;
             }
         oA = 1;
         debugger;
         $('#btnSave').trigger('click');
         return true;
         }
      debugger;
      oA = 1;
      $('#btnSave').trigger('click');
      return true;
     }
     function saveForm(){
        console.log("I want to reach here");
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

I am using `Jquery 2.1.1`

Comment: what I just used this fiddled and it works here? something else must be wrong

Comment: I removed the variable `condition` from the `if` and tried your code, the described behavior not happened to me, it worked as it should. http://jsfiddle.net/fxvdqgb9/

Comment: Yes now the fiddle above is working with dummy condition, don't know why above code is not working in my project.

Comment: anyone have any idea about why my code jumps to if condition before `confirm`, it works in fiddle though?

Comment: Do you have more code than what you show here? Can you provide a more complete and realistic example, with other relevant variables, listeners and functions? Including HTML

Comment: `onceAllowed` function is as is, the only change is condition: `(parseInt($('#LDAtOnce').text()) < parseInt($('#txtLD').val())`

Comment: code reaches the debugger and jumps to if condition then shows `confirm` box later.

Comment: when code reaches `ldays` I set to true but after debugger its value shows `false`